# div Items disappears after hovering

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I am trying to create nested links on side bar navbar using css. When I hover on main links, I am getting the sub link displayed. But when I hover on sub links, its children becomes visible but I am not able to click/hover on them because they are disappearing.

Note : I'm very new to SCSS/CSS and its react app where I'm trying out to add some styling.

Code Sandbox : https://g0mbs.csb.app/

[image]

**HTML Page**

```
import "./styles/style.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <>

      <header>
        <nav>
          <div className="logo">
            <h1>Logo</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="nav__links" >
            <ul >
              <li><a>Link1</a></li>
              <li><a>Link2</a></li>
              <li><a>Link3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <div className="burger">
            <button>
              <div className="line1"></div>
              <div className="line2"></div>
              <div className="line3"></div>
            </button>
          </div>

        </nav>
      </header>
      <div className="main-content-with-side-bar">
        <div className="side-bar">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div>
                <a>Hello1</a>
                <div className="subMenu">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a>link1</a></li>
                    <li><a>link2</a></li>
                    <li><a>link3</a></li>
                    <li><a>link4</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div>
                <a>Hello1</a>
                <div className="subMenu">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a>link1</a></li>
                    <li><a>link2</a></li>
                    <li><a>link3</a></li>
                    <li><a>link4</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div>
                <a>Hello1</a>
                <div className="subMenu">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a>link5</a></li>
                    <li><a>link6</a></li>
                    <li><a>link7</a></li>
                    <li><a>link8</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div>
                <a>Hello1</a>
                <div className="subMenu">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a>link9</a></li>
                    <li><a>link10</a></li>
                    <li><a>link11</a></li>
                    <li><a>link12</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div>
                <a>Hello1</a>
                <div className="subMenu">
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                    <a>link13</a>
                      <div className="sub-subMenu">
                        <ul>
                          <li><a>link13.1</a></li>
                          <li><a>link13.2</a></li>
                          <li><a>link13.3</a></li>
                          <li><a>link13.4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a>link14</a>
                    <div className="sub-subMenu">
                        <ul>
                          <li><a>link14.1</a></li>
                          <li><a>link14.2</a></li>
                          <li><a>link14.3</a></li>
                          <li><a>link14.4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a>link15</a>
                    <div className="sub-subMenu">
                        <ul>
                          <li><a>link15.1</a></li>
                          <li><a>link15.2</a></li>
                          <li><a>link15.3</a></li>
                          <li><a>link15.4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </div></li>
                    <li><a>link16</a>
                    <div className="sub-subMenu">
                        <ul>
                          <li><a>link16.1</a></li>
                          <li><a>link16.2</a></li>
                          <li><a>link16.3</a></li>
                          <li><a>link16.4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </div></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>


        </div>
        <div>

          <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

            Why do we use it?
            It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).


            Where does it come from?
            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

            The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</p>

        </div>
      </div>


      <footer>
        <div>

        </div>
      </footer>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**SCSS**

```
@import "variable";

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
header {
  position: sticky;
  & nav {
    position: sticky;
    background-color: $header-back-color;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    min-height: 8vh;

    & button {
      background-color: $header-back-color;
    }

    & .nav__links {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      overflow: initial;
      & ul {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      & li {
        list-style: none;
      }

      li a {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        // align-items: center;
        color: black;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 14px;
      }
    }

    & .logo {
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 20px;
      float: left;
    }

    & .burger {
      & div {
        width: 25px;
        height: 3px;
        background-color: rgb(3, 3, 3);
        margin: 3px;
      }
      & button {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  }
}

.sideNav {
  & ul {
    min-width: 40px;
  }
  & ul li {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.main-content-with-side-bar {
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;

  & .side-bar {
    width: fit-content;
    min-width: 180px;
    margin: 0 20px;
    background-color: white;
    border-style: solid;

    & li:hover .subMenu{
       
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
    }
    & .subMenu li:hover .sub-subMenu{
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
    }
  }
  & .subMenu {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-left: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
    // opacity: 0.5;
    
  }

  & .sub-subMenu{
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-left: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
  }

  & .side-bar ul li {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  nav {
    & .nav__links {
      display: none;
      justify-content: space-around;
      width: 30%;
    }
    & .burger {
      & button {
        display: block;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hey , please try to add a working sample , could use [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-bird-22n5k) for same

Comment: @Codenewbie I have added it now. You can find the link above.

Answer (score 1):

Without running code, just from my experience, try shortening the margin between the two elements. When you hover over the focus element onto the next there could be space in between where the hover is "deactivated". Make sure you have hover and focus on the other element as well. Or use setTimeOut() on the hovered element to give yourself time to move from one to the next. The former suggestion is the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the disappearance is that the mouse is beyond the hover area. So just increase the hover area.

add this code in your styles.css

```css
ul li :hover::after {
  content: " ";
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Code Sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-gates-qtgyb?file=/src/styles.css

Answer (score 0):

The children of sub links disappear as soon as you try to click them because of the left margin you've given to .sub-submenu. Try decreasing that, and increase the width of the sub links, that will do the trick.